flyway db file version number conflict
We are using fly for DB migration.  We are assigning the version number while merging with main branch.  There will be a conflict when other developer uses the same version there will be a conflict and second person need to assign new number and merge with main branch.  Is there a better process (automated process) to assign unique version number.
version number assignment is manual.
